# Getting noClassDefFoundError

Tags: noclassdeffounderror

I have a class having static final methods.[Say A,B,C] . C invokes another class D[D's package is imported in C] The maven assembly jar[say M.jar] that i have DOESN'T HAVE package D. During runtime, when i try to call A having M.jar in classpath, getting noclasdef error saying D is not prsent.

Why I am getting this? Please share your thoughts

package TEST1 import test.CHECK.TestA; import test.CHECK.TestB; class Factory

{

final static int A() { //some ref to test.CHECK.TestA }

static int B() { //some ref to test.CHECK.TestB }

static int C() { }

I have jar containing this class and package test.CHECK.TestB in that jar.Howver, this jar doesn't contain test.CHECK.TestA.

Now, my client program having this jar calls c(). Then, getting ClassNotFoundException for TestA, though we are not calling A().Why is this so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that you are using Maven, and I supose too that you have two projects.

You have said that in your Jar you have not the testA class, then this class doesn't be added to the classpath and then, the jvm can't locate for use it.

You must consider that any class that you want to use in your application, must be added to the application classpath. This can be added into this Jar, or another Jar, o free, but it must be added.

I hope help you.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs.i am not callingA().then why is it  required during runtime ?, may be required for maven build.Also, it is observed that we are not getting this noclasdef if A() is just static, instead of final static

Comment: i am not supposed to share the code.the scenario is xplained with the sample code i had provided above.i am puzzled why we are not getting the error if meth A is just static.Please let me know what info apart from the code i need to provide